# Spark Streaming Architecture for API Calls

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, spark-streaming

This is more of an investigatory post about the proper way to do something in spark streaming. What I have is a Spark Streaming App that takes in a Kafka Stream. In the Kafka stream for each message we receive I am calling 2 API's that will hit my Spring Boot server running on top of a Postgres database.

The issue is that we are getting over 1 million messages a day which hit our API server at least 2 million times currently. The scale is only growing. We are also planning on adding 2 more calls so essentially doubling the amount of calls to the server. The reason I need to hit the API server is the rules that we apply to each message change over time. The only thing that has come to mind is to get the table behind the API call put it in a variable that the streaming application will call upon. I will then set up another agent that will poll Postgres for table changes and have it update the variables that the streaming job will call upon.

The only issue is that using something like a broadcast variable you can only refresh by restarting the spark streaming application. Does anyone know any framework or tool that I can place in-between the API server/Spark Streaming app to allow us to grow without fear of DDOS'ing?

Answer (score 1):

I guess on top of my mind, there are 3 options:

1. Use a caching proxy, but you are essentially offloading the problem from your DB to a cache. Also comes the problem of cache invalidation. But it can help if you already know the queries that you expect and cache the materialised values. This way you could avoid making multiple calls to the cache server.
2. Have the database log available as a Kafka topic. Now you could join these 2 streams in your spark streaming app. This way you will get changes in database records come directly to your spark application. See if this can help - written originally by Martin Kleppmann: https://github.com/confluentinc/bottledwater-pg
3. Use off-heap memory like Alluxio (which spark integrates nicely with). But the setup is quite complex, since the memory grid has to span your executor nodes. I am not too sure of the viability of this solution, but is something you could investigate.